# MySQL Workbench not found in debian 9 stretch (testing)

Tags: debian, mysql-workbench, stretch

I just moved to `stretch`, two weeks now. Everything is very good, nothing not working but not MySQL Workbench, `apt-get install` gave: 'not found package'. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because it hasn't made it into Debian 9 yet? Since this is not yet released it's very likely just a matter of time until MySQL Workbench hits APT there.

Comment: I see that mysql-workbench 6.3.8+dfsg-1 is now part of Debian Stretch (asof 2017-01-03).